# How to make cmake from brew install the default cmake - Mac OS

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

On the terminal, I've

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.4.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake
```

But when I upgraded the cmake using brew:

```
$ brew upgrade cmake
Error: cmake 3.8.2 already installed
$ brew edit cmake
```

**How to make cmake from brew install the default cmake ?**

My formula file from `brew edit cmake`:

```
class Cmake < Formula
  desc "Cross-platform make"
  homepage "https://www.cmake.org/"
  url "https://cmake.org/files/v3.8/cmake-3.8.2.tar.gz"
  sha256 "da3072794eb4c09f2d782fcee043847b99bb4cf8d4573978d9b2024214d6e92d"
  head "https://cmake.org/cmake.git"

  bottle do
    cellar :any_skip_relocation
    sha256 "2bbeaf0866446737719aca74468290101b0c502065a02ad6e286f69fc0e69c77" => :sierra
    sha256 "74ecc634b8cc6facc828cc434ec16383681736c3c2fc42dd144f78e88bd34842" => :el_capitan
    sha256 "9b53dec241998124c67645be81c8e85db097404115e466cf409caf43add783ae" => :yosemite
  end

  devel do
    url "https://cmake.org/files/v3.9/cmake-3.9.0-rc5.tar.gz"
    sha256 "3ef250f93f1887d99c567542e987938bf1cb49af06275e0081b547765e03e6ac"
  end

  option "without-docs", "Don't build man pages"
  option "with-completion", "Install Bash completion (Has potential problems with system bash)"

  depends_on "sphinx-doc" => :build if build.with? "docs"

  # The `with-qt` GUI option was removed due to circular dependencies if
  # CMake is built with Qt support and Qt is built with MySQL support as MySQL uses CMake.
  # For the GUI application please instead use `brew cask install cmake`.

  def install
    args = %W[
      --prefix=#{prefix}
      --no-system-libs
      --parallel=#{ENV.make_jobs}
      --datadir=/share/cmake
      --docdir=/share/doc/cmake
      --mandir=/share/man
      --system-zlib
      --system-bzip2
      --system-curl
    ]

    if build.with? "docs"
      # There is an existing issue around macOS & Python locale setting
      # See https://bugs.python.org/issue18378#msg215215 for explanation
      ENV["LC_ALL"] = "en_US.UTF-8"
      args << "--sphinx-man" << "--sphinx-build=#{Formula["sphinx-doc"].opt_bin}/sphinx-build"
    end

    system "./bootstrap", *args
    system "make"
    system "make", "install"

    if build.with? "completion"
      cd "Auxiliary/bash-completion/" do
        bash_completion.install "ctest", "cmake", "cpack"
      end
    end

    elisp.install "Auxiliary/cmake-mode.el"
  end

  test do
    (testpath/"CMakeLists.txt").write("find_package(Ruby)")
    system bin/"cmake", "."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `brew link` would work but before you have to purge the `/usr/local/bin/cmake` and `/usr/local/bin/ccmake`:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cmake
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ccmake
brew link cmake
```

Or let `brew` automatically purge them:

```
brew link --overwrite cmake
```

Comment: From where `/usr/local/bin/cmake` come from, was it installed by macOS?